# Automate statistical analyses using apply/apply-like function

Tags: r, statistics, apply, lapply

I have a dataframe that contains 5 columns, each corresponding to a survey item, and a grouping variable. There are a total of 300 observations in my dataframe and each cell entry represents the response given by a student on a given item. I constructed the following reproducible dataframe:

```
set.seed(14)
Group <- rep(c(0, 1), each = 150)
mydf <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(0:1,300,rep=TRUE)))
mydf$Group <- Group
mydf$Group <- factor(mydf$Group, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Group A", "Group B"))
head(mydf); tail(mydf)
> head(mydf); tail(mydf)
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5   Group
1  0  1  1  1  0 Group A
2  1  1  1  1  1 Group A
3  1  1  0  1  0 Group A
4  1  0  0  1  1 Group A
5  1  1  0  1  0 Group A
6  1  0  1  1  1 Group A
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5   Group
295  0  1  1  0  1 Group B
296  0  0  1  0  0 Group B
297  1  1  0  1  0 Group B
298  1  1  0  0  1 Group B
299  0  0  1  0  0 Group B
300  1  1  1  1  1 Group B
```

What I would like to do is perform chi-square test of independence on each survey item 
`X1` to `X5`. So far I have been doing the following [for item 1 (`X1`)]:

```
mydf$X1 <- factor(mydf$X1, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("AGREE", "DISAGREE"))
MyTable <- table(mydf$Group, mydf$X1)
addmargins(MyTable)
chisq.test(MyTable, correct = FALSE)
```

and I would like to use the `lapply` function (or something similar) to automate this process so that I do not have to repeat the preceding code for each of the 5 items. This is particualry important because I have a similar dataframe that contains 50 items and I would like to use the same code to automate those analyses. Any advice on how to proceed? I am having the most trouble with calling out each variable (i.e. `X1`, `X2`, etc.) and I am not sure how to do so. I recently started using R so I do not have a firm understanding of these functions and commands. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you willing to entertain solutions that require additional packages if that yields a more  information rich solution?

Comment: Chuck, Absolutely!

Comment: Take a look at https://ibecav.github.io/CGPfunctions/articles/Using-PlotXTabs2.html it's a bit of overkill for your needs if you're not plotting but it generates the statistics.  I'm happy to add an option to just give the results and not plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the column 'X1' to 'X5', then create a `table` with 'Group' column and o the `chisq.test` to return a `list` of test results

```
out <- lapply(mydf[paste0("X", 1:5)], function(x) 
    chisq.test(table(mydf$Group,
            factor(x, levels = 0:1, labels = c("AGREE", "DISAGREE"))), 
           correct = FALSE))

sapply(out, `[[`, "p.value")
#       X1         X2         X3         X4         X5 
#0.72875061 0.72888976 0.90732945 0.01525704 0.08243538
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little fancier a solution that helps keep things organized...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(infer)


# make a simple vector of the variables you want on one side
exexs <- c("X1", "X2", "X3")
# an easy way to keep track of names
names(exexs) <- exexs

# make our own simple function
MyFunction <- function(data, groupvar, var) 
{ 
  infer::chisq_test(formula = as.formula(paste(var, "~", groupvar)), 
                    x = data, 
                    correct = FALSE) # you can pass options to chisq.test
}

# purrr::map(exexs, ~ MyFunction(data = mydf, groupvar = .x, var = "Group"))
purrr::map_dfr(exexs, ~ MyFunction(data = mydf, groupvar = .x, var = "Group"), .id = "Variable") %>% rbind()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Variable statistic chisq_df p_value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>    <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 X1          0.120         1   0.729
#> 2 X2          0.120         1   0.729
#> 3 X3          0.0136        1   0.907
```

Based on your data

```r
set.seed(14)
Group <- rep(c(0, 1), each = 150)
mydf <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(0:1,300,rep=TRUE)))
mydf$Group <- Group
mydf$Group <- factor(mydf$Group, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Group A", "Group B"))
```